# The easiest way to get css file based on urls to less files in Windows

Tags: css, build, less

I'm curious what's the easiest way to build `total.css` based on `total.less` file that contains list of another imported .less files.

P.S. there are many less files with complicated structure so online tool to get the css file is not a choice in our case.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the easiest way to compile LESS into CSS is using the [LESS.app](http://incident57.com/less/) for mac. Alternatively, the [Offical Documentation for Less](http://lesscss.org/usage/) has a number of other tools you can use, such as the NPM command line utility.

If you wanted to compile LESS in your browser, you could also set up [less.js](http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser) for compiling LESS to CSS on the client-side. (However, I only recommend this for development)